# Self-Signed SSL Certificate for Nginx in Ubuntu 16.04 And authorization (HTTP ERROR 403)

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, flask

I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-adjust-the-firewall) link for self-signed ssl certificate for nginx.My nginx conf is like below:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name myMachineIP;
return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location /static {
    alias /home/users/mysite/app/static;
}

}

server {

  # SSL configuration

   listen 443 ssl http2 myMachineIP;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2 myMachineIP;
   include snippets/self-signed.conf;
   include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

But still I have

`Access to 192.168.1.xxx was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403`

What is wrong with this configurations? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first server block performs a `return 302` so the `location` blocks it contains are ignored.

The second server block contains no `location` blocks, which probably explains the 403 response.

Move the `location` blocks from the first server block to the second.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

Comment: the result is the same :(